# How upload image to firebase storage from Ionic?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic3, firebase-storage

I need help to send an image to firebase storage from ionic. So, i take a picture with this function:

```
  async takePicture() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    try {
      let imageURI = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
      let newImageURI = await this.cropImage(imageURI);
      let imageSanitized = await this.encodeFile(newImageURI);
      this.imgSrc = imageSanitized;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
  }
```

And I crop with this function:

```
  cropImage(imgURI): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      this.cropService.crop(imgURI, { quality: 100 }).then((newImageURI: string) => {
        resolve(newImageURI);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
    })
  }
```

finishing I encode with this function:

```
 encodeFile(ImageURI: string): Promise<any>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.base64.encodeFile(ImageURI).then((base64File: string) => {
        this.imgUri = base64File;
        resolve(this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(base64File));
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
    })
  }
```

this.imgSrc is my sanitized image and this show very well in my file.html. However, I need send this image to firebase storage. For that, I created this function:

```
uploadToStorage(imgString) {
    console.log(imgString);
    this.storage.child('exemplo.JPEG').putString(imgString, 'data_url').then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);

    });
  }
```

imgString is who gets the value of the this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(base64File) or  base64File from function encodeFile.

I don't get an error in my upload function, however, I don't get success, nothing shows up for me.

**How I can send correctly the image to the server?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this:

```
 encodeFile(ImageURI: string): Promise<any>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.base64.encodeFile(ImageURI).then((base64File: string) => {
        this.imgUri = base64File;
        ...
      }, (err) => {
        ...
      })
    })
  }
```

this.imgUri store my image base64 encoding. But is necessary to modify the beginning of it. So split:

```
let messageSplit = this.imgUri.split('data:image/*;charset=utf-8;base64,')[1];
```

add in her place

```
let message64 = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + messageSplit;
```

So upload to the firebase storage.

```
const filePath = `my-pet-crocodile_${ new Date().getTime() }.jpg`;
let task = this.afStorage.ref(filePath).putString(message64, 'data_url');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can capture the image as base64 by using:

```
destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

instead of FILE_URI.

Anyways, to record an image I used the following code with AngularFire2 that works. this.data.image is where I saved base64 of image. Yet, it may get tricky if your encoder is adding ""data:image/jpeg;base64" to the beginning of your base64 string. You may try with or without the added string if this code doesn't work as expected.

```
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageReference } from 'angularfire2/storage/public_api';

//...

const storageRef: AngularFireStorageReference = this.afStorage.ref(`images/${this.userId}/profilePic/`);

storageRef.putString(this.data.image, 'data_url', {
contentType: 'image/jpeg'
}).then(() => {

storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => {

console.log('download url: ' + url);
//function to save download URL of saved image in database

    });
  })
})
```

Comment: I can't to use this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL because I need file_uri to the cropImage() from import { Crop } from '@ionic-native/crop'. Thank very much for you answer.